# Game Development Tag and how to handle questions about game development

Tags: discussion, flagging

I was reviewing answers and questions, and found a few questions related to game development. Some of them tagged with [game-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-development), some not, but most of them would perhaps have better answers, and a better visibility on [GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) .

For example those questions :

- [Good Game that has Scripting Support](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80068/good-game-that-has-scripting-support)
- [Create a behavior/Component based system for games](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89423/create-a-behavior-component-based-system-for-games/126071)

How would you handle those questions ? Are they worth flagging for migration to [GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, there's going to be some overlap in what we cover and what Game Development covers: after all, game development is software development. I think a good question to ask is:

> If this wasn't about a game, or the poster didn't mention it was a game, would it be on-topic for Programmers?

If yes, it's fine here, and the poster's not wrong for asking it here. People can point out that he or she might get better answers on GameDev.SE, and if flagged by the poster, we'd definitely check with the GameDev.SE mods to see if they wanted it, but that's pretty much it.

Also keep in mind the golden rule of migrations: don't migrate crap. Questions should only be migrated if there's a reasonable chance it's going to do well on the destination site. This should block:

- Low quality questions that are about Game Development
- Old, dead questions that might've gotten better answers on Game Development, but the issue is resolved or the timeliness of the question is gone

So, I'd definitely rule out any sort of bulk-migration of questions in the [game-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-development) tag, and maybe really only consider last few days of questions in it.

To get to the specific questions:

- The first question is off-topic: it's a thinly veiled game recommendation question. Off-topic all the way and not worth migrating. I closed it.
- The second one, had it been asked today, I probably would've pinged the GameDev.SE mods to see if they want it: it's ostensibly on-topic here, but they might've had better expertise. Not worth migrating now.

Comment: For the first, would you have considered pinging the Gaming mods? They do have a tag about [modding](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods), which refers to making any modifications to games. I'm not sure if they would want a generic "recommend me a game" question (it doesn't seem like they do, but perhaps).

Comment: @ThomasOwens No: game recommendations are [off-topic on Gaming.SE with extreme prejudice](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1491/3389).

Comment: Although it is a fairly old question. It was originally posted in May 2011 - 7 months ago. I don't know if I would have bothered in this particular instance, for the same reason you didn't ping the GameDev.SE mods for the second. Assuming it was a more recent question, though.

Comment: Ah. I didn't see it in their FAQ, other than a mention disallowing shopping recommendations. I assumed that might possibly be the case, since they frown on shopping recommendations. But then again, it might have been specific enough to be unique and interesting. Thanks for the link.